# Biblatex only displaying name of reference?

Tags: biblatex

I have a latex document in overleaf, which is still fairly simple:

```
\usepackage{datetime}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, headheight=35.4pt, footskip=35.4pt,textwidth=16cm,]{geometry}

\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgcursor}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{kpfonts,baskervald}
\addbibresource{references.bib}



\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
   \fancyheadoffset[loh,ro]{20}
  \fancyhead[R0]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figures/itu.jpeg}}
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont  Johnny John}}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[C]{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont  asse@itu.dk}}
  
  
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}}




\fancyfoot[C]{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont \today} }
\title{Ethical Hacking Project Report }
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}


       \vspace*{0.5cm}



\section*{IDX 2021 : Individual reflexive report}

Here should be a reference \cite{TeamworkSecrets}


\printbibliography

{\fontfamily{fvs}\selectfont  }



\end{document}
```

And my file called "references.bib" looks like so:

```
@article{TeamworkSecrets,
  title={The secrets of great teamwork},
  author={Martine Haas & Mark Mortensen},
  journal={Harvard Business review},
 url = {https://hbr.org/2016/06/the-secrets-of-great-teamwork}
  year={2016},
  publisher={Harvard Business review}
}
```

but in my pdf, the reference is displayed like this:

[image]

And no bibliography is printed.

I have the following steps in my document:

```
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

and then:
\addbibresource{references.bib}
and then printing it:

```
\printbibliography
```

Why does this not work?

**Update**

I now put all my text into a document where references alreqady worked, and slowly pasted all the text in there. It now works, I have no idea why, it's almost the same as before:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, headheight=35.4pt, footskip=35.4pt,textwidth=16cm,]{geometry}

\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgcursor}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{kpfonts,baskervald}
\addbibresource{references.bib}



\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}


\font\myfont=cmr14 at 40pt
\title{\centering sample}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
   \fancyheadoffset[loh,ro]{20}
  \fancyhead[R0]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figures/itu.jpeg}}
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont  Ask H. Sejsbo :18655}}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[C]{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont  ss@itu.dk}}
  
 
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}}


\date{November 2021}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
 \vspace*{0.5cm}
\section*{IDX 2021 : Individual reflexive report}


\subsection*{Working as a team}
Here should be a reference \cite{semtech}



\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run the normalcycle: `pdflatex >biber/bibtex >pdflatex (twice)`?

Comment: You are missing a comma after the `url` field. It should be `url = {https://hbr.org/2016/06/the-secrets-of-great-teamwork},` (this is an error). Additionally, `author={Martine Haas & Mark Mortensen},` is not quite correct either. Regardless of the expected output, several names must be separated with `and`. So the correct value would be `author={Martine Haas and Mark Mortensen},`.

Comment: Unrelated, but the `{\fontfamily{fvs}\selectfont  }` at the end has no visible effect and looks a bit odd.

Comment: @Bernard no, how do I run that in overleaf?

Comment: @moewe thanks for the tips, but it did not seem to do anything

Comment: @Bernard overleaf (or rather latexmk) take care of running biber automatically on overleaf (in the absence of errors)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle/ As I don't use overleaf, I didn't know that. Thanks for the information!